# Create multiple select box with output in string format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up a multiple select box on my project that would provide output into one of my string fields in sql table. So far from what I've figured <% f.select %> with multiple set to true tries to pass an array instead of string, and that doesn't work for my project (in past this was a text field, but now it's required to only allow a selection of preset values to be put in it, and it's on live project, so no drastic changes). I found that doing something like this

```
@keywords = params['keywords']['keywords'].join(', ')
```

would solve my problem, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my controller.

Code fragment I currently have for select in views is:

```
<%= f.select :keywords, ['kw1', 'kw2', 'kw3', 'kw4', 'kw5'], {}, { :multiple => true, :size => 10, :class => 'form-control' } %>
```

code segment from controller for creating new article currently is pretty basic:

```
@article = Article.new
```

"keywords" is a string field in article table.

EDIT: Here is whole controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  PRIORITY_COUNTRIES = %w[RU BR IN CN ZA]
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "***", password: "***", except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    if params[:search] == nil
      @articles = Article.filter(params.slice(:category, :country, :src_url, :date, :lang, :keywords, :title, :rel)).where(is_active: true).order('id DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page])
    else
      @articles = Article.search(params[:search], :without => {:is_active => false}, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 9, :order => :id)
    end

    @countries = ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by do |country|
      priority_index = PRIORITY_COUNTRIES.index(country.alpha2)
      priority_index.present? ? priority_index.to_s : country.name
    end
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update(:is_active => false)

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  def undelete
    @articles = Article.where(is_active: false).paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
  end

  def undestroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update(:is_active => true)

    redirect_to undelete_articles_path
  end


  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :date, :src_url, :country, :author, :category, :keywords, :keywords2, :text, :lang, :rel)
    end
end
```

And model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation do |article| 
    article.keywords.reject!(&:blank?) if article.keywords 
  end

  self.per_page = 9
  include Filterable
  validates :country, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2 }
  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :src_url, presence: true

  validates :keywords2, presence: true
  validates :text, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :date, presence: true

  scope :country, -> (country) { where country: country }
  scope :category, -> (category) { where category: category }
  scope :src_url, -> (src_url) { where('src_url like ?', "%#{src_url}%")}
  scope :date, -> (date) { where date: date }
  scope :keywords, -> (keywords) { where('keywords like ?', "%#{keywords}%")}
  scope :title, -> (title) { where('title LIKE ?', "%#{title}%")}
  scope :rel, -> (rel) { where rel: rel }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, joining the keywords. You may have better luck dealing with the string requirement at the model layer, however.

With the requirement of the column needing a string, but the form and controller passing an array, you may consider doing the following:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def keywords=(value)
    return super value.join(", ") if value.is_a?(Array)

    super
  end
end
```

This will override the `keywords` setter in your model, passing a joined string in the case an array is passed.

Comment: Tried adding your segment to my article.rb model, but it seems to have no effect - I still keep getting blank value passed to db when using my form

Comment: Add all of your controller to the question so we can see what's going on.

Comment: It's your params. You need to specify that `keywords` is an array of values, not a single value. `params.require(:article).permit(..., keywords: [], ...)`

Comment: changing it gives error: c:/.../app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:75: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...gory, keywords: [], :keywords2, :text) ... ^

Comment: Pop it as the last element of the params and that should go away.

Comment: Alright! It finally started working. Now I've found out that my reject segment for eliminating blank first array element is not working though. Error is: undefined method `reject!' for ", kw1, kw2":String

Comment: That's because your array has already been converted to a string. Reject blank values in your `keywords=` method instead, before joining.

Comment: changing to: return super value.reject!(&:blank?).join(", ") if value.is_a?(Array)  worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe using a multi select for a string field will be formatted as a JSON array when passed to the controller.

So, your params that hit the controller would look something like the following:

`{ keywords: { keywords: '["kw1", "kw12"]' } }`

Therefore, to store it in the db as a comma separated string, you'll need to parse it first, using something like the following:

`JSON.parse(params[:keywords][:keywords]).reject(&:blank?).join(', ')`

Couple of gotchas here:

Using a multiselect like this will often (always?) return an empty value first, hence `reject(&:blank?)`.

If the params return `nil`, trying to parse this raises an error, so you might want to define a method to handle this, such as:

```
def string_from_json(vals)
  return unless vals.present?
  JSON.parse(vals).reject(&:blank?).join(', ')
end
```

Or you could rescue `JSON::ParseError` or something.

Finally, you'd call `keywords = string_from_json(params[:keywords][:keywords])` to get the string.

Hope that helps!

---

Edit:

That'll handle the parsing, and then you can assign this in the controller with a simple `@article.keywords = keywords`, `@article.update_attribute(:keywords, keywords)` in the controller, or the approach recommended by Daniel.

Comment: Hmm, calling @keywords like that in controller results in "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass". Any idea for a fix to that? Been getting same a lot when trying one I posted in main post.

Comment: Also using before_validation do |model|
    model.keywords.reject!(&:blank?) if model.keywords
  end - does this do same thing as what you suggested?

Comment: That sounds to me like your params aren't passing correctly - the error likely comes from `params[:keywords]` returning `nil`, and then you're attempting to call `[:keywords]` on NilClass. To save this, if you're using Rails 5, you can use `params.dig(:keywords, :keywords)`. (Older versions require `try(:[], :keywords).try(:[], :keywords)`). This returns nil rather than an error if anything is missing. That help?

Comment: Re your second point, that wouldn't directly work as `blank?` checks the parsed array of vals, and you would be looking at a string by that stage. You _could_ go down this route using something like the method I popped in up there, but it would be tricky figuring out when to fire it (as the unparsed JSON is technically already a string)...

Comment: Getting undefined method `dig' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x9609c48> even though in gemfile my rails version is 5.0.1. Updated head post with whole controller too.

Comment: Ah - my bad, it must be Hash only. The `try` should work, though I'd have a root around to ensure the params are passing in correctly before going too far down this route. `puts` them in the controller or use [Pry](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry-rails/versions/0.3.4) (< it's great, seriously) to check your form is actually providing the params when expected to :)

Comment: Hmm, changing to try now produces this error: undefined method `string_from_json' for #<ArticlesController:0xbb890f0>

Comment: Have you defined the method half way down my answer in your controller? Make sure that's added in, perhaps just below the `private`.

Comment: I see, that was apparently the mistake. Trying out Daniel's method right now, and it seems to work, except I can't get rid of blank first element.